# vsto click-once deploy could not be downloaded

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsto

I am getting an error that my *.vsto could not be downloaded. I thought maybe if I would start a new project the error would go away, but no even with a clean new project without any code I keep getting that error. Is there anything one has to take care of when deploying?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks for the answer, but i fixed it. It somehow had a problem with the standard path. I just had to switch the pathname.I guess the "ö" made some problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiled the project on the machine you are trying to install on, then you'll need to remove the Addin from Excel first (it will be installed from the debug location of your project). Then run the setup.exe file for clickonce.